# Replace elements group with a particular element in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replacewith

I have a list of over 50 elements. These elements are lowercase and uppercase alphabets, numbers, special characters.

eg.

```
sample_list = ['1', '0', 'b', 'B', '2', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', 'A', 'C', 'f', 'D', 'F', '3', 'C', '8', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D']
```

I want to interchange particular elements with a special character.
eg.

```
replacing `A,B,C and 1 with @
replacing `D,E,F and 2 with &
replacing `G,H,I and 3 with (
```

and so on, I have to replace a particular set of elements with 11 selected special characters. Like I replaced few selected elements with 3 of the special characters.

How to do it efficiently.

Comment: Why are ppl always ask how to do it "efficiently" ? How did you try to solve it? What was your bottleneck? What was your problem? Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @PatrickArtner , I had created many lists and then was searching which list the element belongs and then replacing it with the resp special character. It wasn't efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it using `translate` method following way:

```
sample_list = ['1', '0', 'b', 'B', '2', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', 'A', 'C', 'f', 'D', 'F', '3', 'C', '8', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D']
t = ''.maketrans('ABC1DEF2GHI3','@@@@&&&&((((')
out = [i.translate(t) for i in sample_list]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['@', '0', 'b', '@', '&', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', '@', '@', 'f', '&', '&', '(', '@', '8', '@', '&', '@', '@', '@', '&']
```

`maketrans` method of `str` is used for creating translation table, just feed it with two equal length `str`s with first consisting of keys and second of values. `translate` method accept that table and replace characters accordingly, or left original intact if that there is not such key in table.

EDIT: As noted by Olivier Melançon it can be used only if you want to replace 1 character with 1 character.

Comment: It's neat, although it's good to point out that this method will not be able to extend to a sample list with elements of more than one character.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define your replacement rules, by example with a `dict`. In particular, since `dict` allows *O(1)* access, this is as fast as your method will be able to get time-complexity-wise: that is solve it in a single traversal of the list.

You can then traverse the list and replace each element if it has a replacement rule.

```
rules = {
    'A': '@',
    'B': '@',
    'D': '&',
    'E': '&'
}

for i, c in enumerate(sample_list):
    if c in rules:
        sample_list[i] = rules[c]
```

If you wish to create a new list instead of mutating the initial one, you can use a list-comprehension

```
new_list = [rules.get(c, c) for c in sample_list]
```

### Example

```
rules = {
    'A': '@',
    'B': '@',
    'D': '&',
    'E': '&'
}

sample_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

new_list = [rules.get(c, c) for c in sample_list]

print(new_list)
```

### Output

```
['@', '@', '@', 'C', '&', '&', 'F']
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? There is no reason this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and set all of your maping in dictionary:

```
chars = {"@": ["A", "B", "C", "1"], "&": ["D", "E", "F", "2"]}
sample_list = ['1', '0', 'b', 'B', '2', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', 'A', 'C', 'f', 'D', 'F', '3', 'C', '8', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D']

for k, v in chars.items():
    for value in v:
        if value in sample_list:
            ind = [index for index, val in enumerate(sample_list) if val == value]            
            for x in ind:
                sample_list[x] = k


print(sample_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function:

Ex for the first replacement:

```
new_list = map(lambda x: '@' if x in ('A', 'B', 'C') else x, sample_list)
```

sample_list can be a string too (each character is one element, but map will return an array either way).

On a "string" list, you could just use the replace method:

```
compact_list = ''.join(sample_list)
new_compact_list = compact_list.replace('A', '@').replace('B', '@').replace('C', '@')
```

Of course if the source list is variable, write a loop around it...

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple function and refine it.

Simple would be using 3 `sets` (for lookup set is better then lists) - if sets do not need to mutate, use `frozensets` instead. Use a simple loop - straight forward:

```
sample_list = ['1', '0', 'b', 'B', '2', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', 'A', 'C', 'f', 'D', 'F', '3', 'C', '8', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D'] 

new_list = []
for item in sample_list:
    abc = frozenset("ABC")    # frozensets do not change, they are immuteable
    dfe = frozenset("DEF")    # and fast for lookups. this is less performant
    ghi = frozenset("GHI")    # then using a dict - but it works as well

    if item in abc:
        new_list.append("@")
    elif item in dfe:
        new_list.append("&")
    elif item in ghi:
        new_list.append("(")
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['1', '0', 'b', '@', '2', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', '@', '@', 'f', '&', '&', '3', '@', '8', '@', '&', '@', '@', '@', '&']
```

To get more fancy use a dictionary and list-comp:

```
transform = {"A":"@", "B":"@", "C":"@", 
             "D":"&", "E":"&", "F":"&", 
             "G":"(", "H":"(", "I":"("}

new_list = [ transform.get(i,i) for i in sample_list]
```

Output:

```
['1', '0', 'b', '@', '2', '6', 'a', '7', '9', '5', 'c', 'd', '4', '@', '@', 'f', '&', '&', '3', '@', '8', '@', '&', '@', '@', '@', '&']
```

See:

- [set()/frozenset()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)